# Python Error: "TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' "

Tags: python-2.7

Ive read your previous answers about this error onthe site, but not sure exactly how i could change my code to fix it in mine. It's a long code, sorry about that :$

```
import random

#QUESTION 1a:

#CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION:

    def makestk():                  #This function returns a new stack in the form of a tagged tuple.
        stk=('stack',[])            #Inserts the tagged tuple into a variable.
        return stk                  #Returns variable holding tagged tuple(empty stack).

#PREDICATE FUNCTION: 

    def emptystk(stk):              #This function returns True if the stack is empty or false if the stack is not empty.
        if stk[1] == []:            #Checks if the second variable of the tagged tuple is an empty list or not.
            return True             #Returns True if the second variable of the tagged tuple is indeed an empty list.
        else:
            return False            #Returns False if the second variable of the tagged tuple is a list containing element(s).

#MUTATOR FUNCTIONS:

    def contents(s):                #This function is created to aid the mutator functions.
        return s[1]                 #Returns the second variable of the tagged tuple.

    def pushstk(stk,ele):           #This function accepts a stack and an element and adds the element to the stack at position0.
        contents(stk).insert(0,ele) #Uses the helper function to get the second variable of the tagged tuple and inserts the element to the stack at position0.
        #return stk                 #Returns the updated version of the tagged tuple entered.

    def popstk(stk):                #This function accepts a stack and an element; and adds the element to the stack at position0.
        contents(stk).pop(0)        #Uses the helper function to get the second variable of the tagged tuple and removes the element in position0 of the stack.
        #return stk                 #Returns the updated version of the tagged tuple entered.

#QUESTION 1b:

#CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION:

    def makecell((x,y)):                        #This function accepts a tuple which consists of the x and y co-ordinate of the cell being created.
        cell=('cell',(x,y),['t','b','r','l'])   #Inserts the tagged tuple into a variable.(The list represents the four walls of the cell: t-top,b-bottom,r-right,l-left)
        return cell                             #Returns a cell in the form of a tagged tuple.

#ACCESSOR FUNCTIONS:

    def getx(cell):                #This function returns the x co-ordinate of the cell.
        return cell[1][0]          #Returns the first value of the second variable in the tagged tuple.

    def gety(cell):                #This function returns the y co-ordinate of the cell.
        return cell[1][1]          #Returns the second value of the second variable in the tagged tuple.

    def getwalls(cell):            #This function returns the lsit of walls that are intact for a given cell.
        return cell[2]             #Returns the third variable of the tagged tuple.

#MUTATOR FUNCTIONS:

    def removetw(cell):            #This function removes the top wall of the cell.
        getwalls(cell).remove('t') #Uses the 'getwalls' function and removes the first value of list.
        return cell                #Returns the updated version of the list.

    def removebw(cell):            #This function removes the bottom wall of the cell.
        getwalls(cell).remove('b') #Uses the 'getwalls' function and removes the second value of the list.
        return cell                #Returns the updated version of the list.

    def removerw(cell):            #This function removes the right wall of the cell.
        getwalls(cell).remove('r') #Uses the 'getwalls' function and removes the third values of the list.
        return cell                #Returns the updated version of the list.

    def removelw(cell):            #This function removes the left wall of the cell.
        getwalls(cell).remove('l') #Uses the 'getwalls' function and removes the fourth values of the list.
        return cell                #Returns the updated version of the list.

#QUESTION 2:

    def makegrid(w,h):              #This function accepts the width and height of the desired grid/matrix of cells and creates it.
        grid=[]                     #Inserts an empty list into a variable.
        for x in range (0,(w)):     #Allows x to traverse through the range of 0 to the width value.
            for y in range (0,(h)): #Allows y to traverse through the range of 0 to the height value.
                tup=(x,y)                     #Inserts the values x and y into a variable.
                grid.append(makecell(tup))    #Inserts/updates the variable 'tup' into the list 'grid' and runs function until x and y have completely traversed through the ranges.
        return grid                           #Returns the updated version of grid.

#QUESTION 3:

    def getneighbours (cell,w,h):                 #This function accepts a cell and the width and height of the grid.
        lst = []
        x = getx(cell)
        y = gety(cell)
        if y + 1 <= h:
            lst = lst + [makecell((x,y + 1))]
        if y - 1 >= 0:
            lst = lst + [makecell((x,y - 1))]
        if x + 1 <= w:
            lst = lst + [makecell((x + 1,y))]
        if x - 1 >= 0:
            lst = lst + [makecell((x - 1,y))]
        return lst                                   #Returns the neighbouring cell walls.

#QUESTION 4: 

    def removewalls(c1,c2):                       #This function accepts two cells and removes the walls common between the two.accepts two cells
        if gety(c1)==gety(c2)-1:                  #Checks if c1 is above c2.
            removetw(c2) and removebw(c1)         #Removes the corresponding common wall shared between the cells.
        elif gety(c1)==gety(c2)+1:                #Checks if c1 is below c2.
            removetw(c1) and removebw(c2)         #Removes the corresponding common wall shared between the cells.
        elif getx(c1)==getx(c2)-1:                #Checks if c1 is to the left of c2.
            removerw(c1) and removelw(c2)         #Removes the corresponding common wall shared between the cells.
        elif getx(c1)==getx(c2)+1:                #Checks if c1 is to the right of c2.
            removerw(c2) and removelw(c1)         #Removes the corresponding common wall shared between the cells.
    cell0=makecell((0,0))
    cell1=makecell((0,1))

#QUESTION 5:

    def wallsintact(grid,neighbours):
        return [x for x in grid if x in neighbours and getwalls(x)==['t','b','r','l']]

#QUESTION 6:

    def createmaze(w,h):
        stack=makestk()
        totalcells=w*h
        grid=makegrid(w,h)
        cell=grid[random.randrange(totalcells)]
        strt=1
        while (strt<totalcells):
            neighbours=getneighbours(cell,w,h)
            intact=wallsintact(grid,neighbours)
            while intact!=[]:
                maze=intact[random.randrange(len(intact))]
                intact.remove(maze)
                removewalls(cell,maze)
                pushstk(stack,maze)
            strt=strt+1
            cell=popstk(stack)
        return grid
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is much more likely to get answered if you [format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) correctly. Also, you should include the error back trace so that we don't need to look through all of the code to find the error. Before posting, you should look at [other posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+%27int%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27__getitem__%27) describing similar problems on SO. Finally, Google is [your friend](http://bit.ly/Ts3oyk).